# XSD expects right element of wrong namespsace

Tags: xml, xsd

I want to define a schema in namespace "foo" that imports a schema in namespace "bar" with complex types defined and makes references to types in "bar". What am I missing to make this validate? MWE below.

Root schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns:f="foo" xmlns:b="bar" targetNamespace="foo">

<import schemaLocation="Import.xsd" namespace="bar"/>

<element name="root" type="f:Root"/>

<complexType name="Root">
    <sequence>
        <!--<element ref="b:imported"/>-->
        <element name="imported" type="b:ImportedType"/>
    </sequence>
</complexType>
</schema>
```

Imported schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    targetNamespace="bar"
    elementFormDefault="qualified">
<complexType name="ImportedType"/>
<!--
<element name="imported">
    <complexType/>
</element>
-->
</schema>
```

XML instance:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<f:root xmlns:f="foo" xmlns:b="bar">
    <b:imported/>
</f:root>
```

Result:
**Element '{bar}imported': This element is not expected. Expected is ( {foo}imported ).**

If I change design pattern from Venetian Blind to Salami Slice (toggle comments in schemas) everything works. But all our other schemas are in VB so I would prefer not to change for this case.

Tried to validate with both xmllint and notepad++

Comment: So your goal is to have `b:imported` instead of `f:imported`?

Comment: The goal is to let the XML document remain as is. I can't change the layout of it. I can't change the layout of the imported schema either since it is not ours. I'm trying to understand why it thinks "imported" should belong to namespace foo while I've specified it's type as "b:ImportedType" (bar)

Comment: You're a bit mistaken about that. The _type_ is still in `b`, but your element `imported` is not imported, it declared in your schema.

Comment: Yes, I just realized it as I had posted the answer to your comment. So to use a child element in a different namespace do I have to <element ref="..."/> to "break out" of the current namespace?

Comment: I always thought so, but I also see a `targetNamespace` attribute in the schema spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/#dcl.elt.local
So I'd try writing `targetNamespace="bar"`, or maybe a name `b:imported`. I don't have IDE at hand, could you please try it?

Comment: It works if I define "entry points" as elements (containing a complexType) and the rest may be defined solely as complexTypes. I was mistaken about the whole targetNamespace thing (your 2nd comment) and apparently you need element refs to escape a namespace. Make an answer about it and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You expected to have `b:imported` instead of `f:imported`.

The thing is, you have imported and used a *type*. And your type `ImportedType` is still in `b`.

Your element `imported` is, however (despite what the name says) not imported from `b`, but declared in `f`.

Therefore `f:imported` is correct and expected.

If you want to "escape" the namespace with the element, declare `imported` in `f` and use an element reference instead:

```
<xs:element ref="b:imported"/>
```